# Help with If Else formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I want to run an if else on base of a commandfield on each row,

For example

```
 If {CommandField=0} Update counter by 1 return counter

 else if {CommandField=1} return 'Reporting'
```

I tried it but having error

```
     stringVar layerType; 
shared numberVar layNo;

     if({Command.ISREPORT}=0) then
           layNo:=layNo+1;layerType:=layNo;layerType

     else if ({Command.ISREPORT}=1) then
      layerType:='Reporting'; layerType
```

results should be like

```
ISREPORT   LayerNo
   0         1
   0         2 
   0         3
   0         4
   1       'Reporter'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand but is this right:

```
stringVar layerType; 
shared numberVar layNo;

     if({Command.ISREPORT}=0) then
     (     layNo:=layNo+1;
           layerType:=ToText(layNo);
           layerType;
     )
     else 
     (  if ({Command.ISREPORT}=1) then
           layerType:='Reporting'; 
           layerType
     )
```

...which can be simplified to this:

```
shared numberVar layNo;

     if({Command.ISREPORT}=0) then
     (     
           layNo:=layNo+1;
           ToText(layNo);
     )
     else 
     (if ({Command.ISREPORT}=1) then
           'Reporting';)
```

..assuming the value of ISREPORT can only be 0 or 1 then we can further simplify to this:

```
shared numberVar layNo;

     if({Command.ISREPORT}=0) then
     (     
           layNo:=layNo+1;
           ToText(layNo);
     )
     else
     (
       layNo:=0;
       'Reporting';
     )
```

**Update** - I've changed the last example to reset the counter on 'reporting'.

Edit:
change the ToText(.. to this `ToText(layNo,0);` (sets decimal places to zero)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Dog Ears. It was really helpful and working fine. I guess the problem was using 'else if'. Would the counter resume from the end if another '0' is encountered after 1 ? Like  in sequence 0,0,0,1,0 => (1,2,3, Reporting, 4) ?

Comment: And yeah, thanks for the incremental improved versions. All of them work with no hassle. I tried the zero tip also and it removed the trailing zeroes :)

Comment: @Damien Joe: to reset you'd have to reset on the '1' and set layNo to = 0, I've updated the answer.